# Create Multiple GET requests by changing request Body in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a get request which has a request body and return a response relevant to that. I want to iterate 100 times this request but with a small change in the request body.

Here is the example:

req : `<someurl>/myproject/getuser`

request body:

```
{
    "id" : "User1",
    "department" : "maths",
    "des" : "maths-user1"
}
```

I want to send 100 requests to this url by changing request body id from User1 to User100 and des from maths-user1 to maths-user100 . How I can do this in JMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved in many ways. Here is an example:

- Add your sampler (get request) into a loop controller and give the loop count value to 100.

[image]

- In your get request sample body will be like:

  ```
  {"id" : "User${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)}","department" : "maths","des" : "maths-user${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)}"  
  }
  ```

This way you will get the below results:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540911/stop-sending-requests-by-checking-the-response-body-in-jmeter

Is it possible for you to answer this also if you can?