# Stop Sending Requests By Checking the Response Body in JMeter

Tags: json, rest, jmeter

I want to keep calling to a REST API until the Response Body contains a 100 elements.

Here is the example:

request : `someurl/get/data`

response :
1st API call :  (2elements included)

```
{
  "items" : [
          {
            "name": "abc",
            "id"  : "ajdiw123"
          },
          {
            "name": "abc",
            "id"  : "ajdiw123345"
          }
  ]
}
```

2nd API call : (4 elements)

```
{
  "items" : [
          {
            "name": "abc",
            "id"  : "ajdiw123"
          },
          {
            "name": "def",
            "id"  : "ajdiw145"
          },
          {
            "name": "afc",
            "id"  : "ajdiw113"
          },
          {
            "name": "bbc",
            "id"  : "ajdiw199"
          }
  ]
}
```

like this response body included elements can changed. At some point it will return 100 elements with 100 different ids there. How I can identified that and stop sending the requests to the endpoint using JMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved in multiple ways depending on your test plan.

Add a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and a [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) to your request.

JSON Extractor Settings will be like:

[image]

JSR223 Assertion code will be like:

```
String totalIDs = vars.get("id_matchNr");
Integer result = Integer.valueOf(totalIDs);
if (result == 100){
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}
```

After that, just add a [Result Status Action Handler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Result_Status_Action_Handler) to that request so it will stop the execution for the specific thread:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But it didn't stop. It's still running continuously. I'll add what I did in the question.

Comment: I've shown you the process, you should write your own code accordingly! Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62020935/jmeter-how-to-run-two-parallel-thread-sets-consecutively Can you help me with this issue please :) @Jahan

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Add a post processor in your request. A JSON Extractor to extract any of the unique array attribute say ID. JSON extractor should have a **match number field set to -1** and name set as **requestid** and expression as **$..id**
- Debug sampler
- All this should be inside a While Controller which will have a condition 
  ${__jexl3(${requestid_matchNr} != 100)}. "requestid_matchNr" will come from Debug Sampler response.