# JMeter How to run two parallel thread sets consecutively

Tags: testing, jmeter

I need to create a Thread Group Using JMeter with 5 Thread Groups.

[image]

This is how I want this test to run:

1. Thread 1 and 2 Starts Parallelly. (But Thread 1 only runs once and Thread 2 runs till it gets a success)
2. Once Thread 2 finishes running, Thread 3 and 4 should start running parrallaly.(But Thread 3 only runs once and Thread 4 runs till it gets a success)
3. Once Thread 4 finishes Thread 5 needs to start.

Really appreciate if you can guide me to achieve this task.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't need to pass anything between the Thread Groups the easiest would be just putting all the requests under one Thread Group and control the concurrency using [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

   [image]
2. If you need to pass something between Thread Groups, i.e. Thread3 requires some data from Thread2 - consider using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)

Both plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: This is very useful, Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I updated the question. Can you reconsider the question and answer again please!